# Is there any way to ask "Display Over Other Apps" Permission in flutter in different way?

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, android-permissions

I need to ask Display Over Other apps Permission for my Flutter app... When I request permission using `permission_handler` plugin, I get the output as seen below in **Image 1**... I need to get the output like we can see in **Image 2**... That is, the user can give permission immediately, without searching for the app's name in the long list as seen in **Image 1**...

Also, I tried using Android Intent in Flutter, and also got the same output as **Image 1**... Here's the AndroidIntent code I used...

```
AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
     action: "android.settings.action.MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION",
     data: "package:login.vway.taxi",
);
intent.launch();
```

Anyone suggest me how can I request permission to user so that the output is like the same as **Image 2**

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2:
[image]